# Open source GPS+IMU sensor fusion?

Tags: filters, kalman-filters, filtering, sensor

Are there any Open source implementations of GPS+IMU sensor fusion (loosely coupled; i.e. using GPS module output and 9 degree of freedom IMU sensors)? -- kalman filtering based or otherwise

I see a few open source implementations of IMU sensor fusion that merge accel/gyro/magneto to provide the raw-pitch-yaw, but haven't found anything that includes GPS data to provide filtered location and speed info.